# Deleting Specific child object while Updating Parent Object

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am working on Spring boot and spring jparepository.

I am having Object say "department" and which is having a list of employees .
My Department creation is working fine, Issue i am facing when i was updating the department object.

From Rest Api I am getting Department object which contains the list of employees that need to be updated/deleted/added in database, My Employee Entity is having a transient property say operation on basis of that i am filtering out which operation  need to be perform on employee update / delete / add.

**Department Entity-**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="department")
public class  Department{

    @Id @Column(name="dept_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="dept_name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name="dept_code")
    public String code;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH},orphanRemoval = true, 
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="department")
    public List<Employee> employees;
}
```

**Employee Entity -**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id     @Column(name="emp_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="emp_name")
    public String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    public Department  department;

    @Transient
    public String operation;
}
```

**Department Service Layer -**

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class DepartmentService {

    public Department createDepartment(Department department) {

        Department dept = departmentRepository.save(department);
        for (Employee emp : department.getEmployees()) {
            emp.setDepartment(department);
            employeeRepository.save(emp);
        }
        return dept;
    }

    public Department updateDepartment(Department department) {

        Department dept = departmentRepository.save(department);
        if (!dept.getEmployees().isEmpty()) {
            for (Employee emp : department.getEmployees()) {
                if (emp.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) 
                    employeeRepository.deleteById(emp.getId());
                 else 
                    employeeRepository.save(emp);
            }
        }
        return dept;
    }

    public Department getDepartment(int id) {
        return departmentRepository.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

**After debugging what i got is -**

1. My Service layer is annotated with @Transactional,  when i am trigerring get Api for dept. it is returning proxy object of department and in service layer list of employees is not getting fetched . when model mapper is converting dept object to deptBean at that time it is fetching list of employees. Why  I am able to fetch list of employee object from proxy object outside transaction.
2. In Update function of Service layer also , I am returning proxy object but that is not able to fetch list of employees in Service layer too.Also , I tried calling get function of service layer in after department updation controller even that is also not able to fetch list of employees.

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    DepartmentService departmentService;

     private ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dept", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<DepartmentBean> updateDepartment(@RequestBody DepartmentBean deptBean) {

        Department dept = modelMapper.map(deptBean, Department.class);
        Department persistedDept = departmentService.updateDepartment(dept);
        Department d  = departmentService.getDepartment(persistedDept.getId());
        DepartmentBean userDTO = modelMapper.map(d, DepartmentBean.class);
        return  new ResponseEntity<DepartmentBean>(userDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dept/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<DepartmentBean> getDepartment(@PathVariable int id) {

        Department dept = departmentService.getDepartment(id);
        DepartmentBean userDTO = modelMapper.map(dept, DepartmentBean.class);
        return  new ResponseEntity<DepartmentBean>(userDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Json used for update Department Api

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "DEPT061",
    "code": "CODE061",
    "employees": [

    ]
}
```

Comment: please let me know if any other help is required.if needed i can provide sample code

Answer (score 1):

> My Service layer is annotated with @Transactional, when i am trigerring get Api for dept. it is returning proxy object of department and in service layer list of employees is not getting fetched . when model mapper is converting dept object to deptBean at that time it is fetching list of employees. Why I am able to fetch list of employee object from proxy object outside transaction.

You have a few ways you can handle this problem.

One way, which I highly *do not suggest* but is available, is to mark the collection to be eagerly loaded in your mapping model like this

```
// inside your Department entity
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Employee> employees;
```

The problem with this approach is that while it will work, it introduces what we call `SELECT N+1` where basically the persistence provider will fetch the `Department` and will follow-up by issing a select to populate the collection.  When selecting 1 `Department` this is obviously not so much of a problem.  It becomes a major performance issue when you select multiple departments like this

```
SELECT * FROM Department // returns 3 rows
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE departmentId = :row1DepartmentId   
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE departmentId = :row2DepartmentId
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE departmentId = :row3DepartmentId
```

For a large result-set, this can be a major performance hit.

The best and *suggested* way to couple your association fetches at query-time based on what the query's caller requires.  In other words, don't use `#findOne()` but instead write a specialized query that returns what your code needs.

```
@Query( "SELECT d FROM Department d JOIN FETCH employees WHERE d.id = :id" )
public List<Department> getDepartmentWithEmployees(Integer id)
```

This will avoid the lazy initialization issue because you're explicitly asking the provider to give you all the information you need up-front before you leave the transaction boundary.

> In Update function of Service layer also , I am returning proxy object but that is not able to fetch list of employees in Service layer too.Also , I tried calling get function of service layer in after department updation controller even that is also not able to fetch list of employees.

Because we addressed the lazy-initialization issues with the call to `#getDepartment`, this should no longer be a problem.

> From Rest Api I am getting Department object which contains the list of employees that need to be updated/deleted/added in database, My Employee Entity is having a transient property say operation on basis of that i am filtering out which operation need to be perform on employee update / delete / add.

A couple nick-picks here.

I first would consider decoupling your JSON objects and your database entity objects.  You're effectively tainting your database model with a transient field just so you can pass some *data* from the controller to your persistence layer.  This to me feels wrong.

If you don't want to decouple your json objects and entity models, then at least place that transient data in a separate context object which you populate separately and provide to your update process

```
public class EmployeeOperationContext {
  private Integer employeeId;
  private EmployeeOperation operation;
}

public enum EmployeeOperation {
  INSERT,
  UPDATE,
  DELETE
}

public void updateDepartment(
     Department dept, 
     List<EmployeeOperationContext> contexts) { 
  ...
}
```

The key point to take away here is that at any time, you may need to refactor your database model to perform better or to provide a better view into your database in a more normalized fashion.  When doing so, that does not mean your REST API will change.

Conversely, the same can happen where the consumers of the REST API dictate changes but you don't want those changes to impact your database model.

The whole point of your controller and service tiers are to bridge those gaps rather than to be *passthru* helpers.  So use them as they're intended.  You might see this as a lot of overhead, but it will most definitely improve your design and reduce the impact of changes on either end of the spectrum having a larger ripple impact.

**UPDATE**

The issue with your `Department` update is that you're blindly taking the data from the incoming rest call and pushing it to the database without merging it with existing data.  In other words, look at this

```
// Here you covert your DepartmentBean JSON object to a Department entity
Department dept = modelMapper.map( deptBean, Department.class );
// Here you overwrite the existing Department with JSON data
Department persistedDept = departmentRepository.save( dept );
// ^ this department no longer has employees because of this
```

There are several ways to solve this but they all involve the same premise.  The main concern here is that you must first fetch the existing department object from the database so that you have the right state and then you apply the incoming changes.  In short:

```
// Fetch department from the database
Department department = departmentRepository.get( departmentId );
// overlay the DepartmentBean data on the Department
modelMapper.map( deptBean, department, Department.class );
// save department
departmentRepository.save( department );
```

What I would ultimately then do is modify the service method to take the `DepartmentBean` as input and do the above inside the service:

```
@Transactional
public void updateDepartment(DepartmentBean jsonModel) {
  // Now we can read the department & apply a read lock in the trx
  Department department = repository.getWithLock( departmentId );

  // Overlay the json data on the entity instance
  modelMapper.map( jsonModel, department, Department.class );

  // save the changes
  repository.save( department );
}
```

You can add the other service logic you had in your original update here as well to handle the deletion of employees as needed.  The beauty is that since this is all contained in a service method that is transaction bound, you no longer need that transient field in the employee entity.  You can simply read the operation from the incoming bean argument and call the appropriate employee repository method directly.

Comment: i will try and let you know

Comment: i tried fetch type eager , Now get Api is working fine as expected but still same issue in update.

Comment: Another thing , I don't think lazy initalisation is a issue infact it is a feature.what i believe is some config is wrong because of that such issue are coming

Comment: I am using enum only as a sample code i used string

Comment: if you need sample code i can provide that in which issue is coming

Comment: Chances are your update operation when  you delete an employee, you're not properly removing it from the department.  You should be in the habit of modifying both sides of a bidirectional relationship regardless which side owns the relationship.  Without more detail its hard to understand what problem you face now.

Comment: #Naros please find my json that i used for update department api in which i am not touching employees simply updating department and at the end expecting full department object.

Comment: I would expect if your update controller call is running with 2 sessions (one for update and one for get), it should work.  Can you post the exception stacktrace you get?

Comment: i am not getting any exception.It seems you didn't understood the issue. I created a department with 3 employee's and after that i am updating my department (cascade type is remove ) not updating any employee then i am fetching the latest updated department (which doesn't conatin any employee but they exist in db.)